# PyQt не удается получить параметр

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, qt5, pyqt5

Ошибка:

> NameError: name self not defined

Код:

```
class MserverGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mservergui.Ui_TechControlMSRV):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MserverGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setFixedSize(self,500,500)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.consettings.hide()
        self.conbtn.clicked.connect(self.connecttocli)
        self.msrvcon.clicked.connect(self.connecttosrv)
    def connecttocli (a, b):
        a = None
        b = None
        return
    def connecttosrv (a, b):
        a = None
        b = None
        ip = self.masterSrv.text() #Вот тут ошибка
        try:
            sock.connect((ip, 14061))
        except Exception:
            QtWidgets.QDialog.QErrorMessage(self, "Невозможно подключиться к указанному IP.")
            return
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Небольшой совет сначала: выкладывайте текст ошибки полностью (лучше всего полный трейсбек), а то так приходится гадать, а телепаты и гадалки как правило в отпуске.

Теперь код. Во-первых, проверьте отступы. Я конечно надеюсь, что вы при копипасте кода забыли их сделать, но все же. Во-вторых, если `connecttocli` и `connecttosrv` это методы класса, то им тоже надо передавать `self` в качестве параметра (всегда методам класса надо передавать параметр `self`):

```
class MserverGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mservergui.Ui_TechControlMSRV):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MserverGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setFixedSize(self,500,500)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.consettings.hide()
        self.conbtn.clicked.connect(self.connecttocli)
        self.msrvcon.clicked.connect(self.connecttosrv)
    def connecttocli(self, a, b):
        a = None
        b = None
        return
    def connecttosrv(self, a, b):
        a = None
        b = None
        ip = self.masterSrv.text() #Вот тут ошибка
        try:
            sock.connect((ip, 14061))
        except Exception:
            QtWidgets.QDialog.QErrorMessage(self, "Невозможно подключиться к указанному IP.")
            return
        return
```

Comment: Отступы поставить забыл при копировании. Код починен, теперь ошибка в другом месте, но тут я уже сам разберусь